# The charge of an electron is a constant. In any case?

Tags: particle-physics, electrons, charge, standard-model, strong-force

Since Millikan it is obvious that the charge of the electron can be measured as a result of the force exerted by an external electric field. What we get in detail is the charge from the excess of electrons in a water or oil droplet.

I wonder why we are so convinced that a free electron does not lose part of its charge on its way to the nucleus, on its way to a bound electron.

I am fully aware that the direct measurement of charge reduction is impossible, isn't it? Take it, if you want, as a subquestion.

The implication that electrons partially lose their charge has some consequences that fall into the realm of observable physics.

1. applied to the electron, the proton must exhibit the same behaviour A free proton has the charge +1. The proton that is bound in the nucleus does not. This makes the strong force obsolete or worth considering.
2. an electron without kinetic energy, captured by an ion, loses energy on the way to a bound electron. Where does the energy come from? From the electric field of the electron, which weakens.

My question: What are the inconsistencies of a hypothesis of the charge loss of a bound electron?

And please just this once, for some of you, stay away from the impulsive reaction that this is not mainstream physics. Physics is a living science, not a collection of truth theories.

---

Edit after Johns answer

> The energy levels of the hydrogen atom are calculated for a constant negative charge on the electron and constant positive charge on the proton. If the charges were to decrease (keeping the total charge zero) the energy levels would differ from those calculated (and observed).

To do so, the approach is that the charge has a potential energy value from infinity to the point it is away from the nucleus? With the one hand we apply energy and with the other we take energy away by the emission of photons.

Full aware what I was doing, I wrote in the question that even an electron in rest, near the nucleus, will “fall” to it with the release of EM radiation. This couldn’t be the claimed potential energy from infinity nor kinetic energy. It is taken from the electron itself, its mass or/and its field.

Maybe that is semantic. But the consequence lays in the need or not-need of the strong force. It lays in the understanding, why the electron-proton interaction is stable at the end and quantized for stimulated states. And why the particle-antiparticle annihilation happens.

---

Edit after sinteticos comment

> the photon has no charge, so emitting or absorbing a photon do not change the charge

@sintetico, yes, the photon does not has charge. But the e and the p have, and they have opposite charges. Furthermore, they have (measured, really real) magnetic fields.

The photon, in turn, has a swelling electric and magnetic field component. How this does not mach the robbery of some field strength from e and p to the energy quant?

---

One more addition to Johns profound answer

> In quantum field theory the object that we call the electron is strictly defined only in the limiting case where is isolated from all other particles. In this case it is represented by a Fock state of the field and this state has the charge −. **However a bound electron is not a Fock state. In fact we don't have a simple description of this state but we can approximate it as a sum of Fock states and it is these extra states in the sum that represent the virtual particles.**

What the reduced electric charge idea claims is the not-need of virtual photons. It changes the claimed sum of Fock states for the not simple descriptionable states by a simpler model. Let the model be not right, but it is worth to calculate it first, and then throw it away. For the beginning, what are the inconsistencies and - again and again - not the implications to the existing theories?

Comment: Physics.SE is not a discussion forum for non-mainstream theories. Additionally, questions should be self-contained and not need an edit after every answer they receive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The energy levels of the hydrogen atom are calculated for a constant negative charge on the electron and constant positive charge on the proton. If the charges were to decrease (keeping the total charge zero) the energy levels would differ from those calculated (and observed).

More generally, assuming that you accept quantum field theory as a good description of fundamental particles, the charge is a property of the quantum field. The reason electrons all have the same charge is because they are excitations of the same quantum field. There is no mechanism in quantum field theory for the charge of an electron to change depending on whether it is bound into an atom or not.

There is a sense in which it could be argued that the charge in a hydrogen atom does change, and it is along the lines of the mechanism you suggest, though it is not simply that an electron charge changes as it approaches the proton. In quantum field theory the object that we call the electron is strictly defined only in the limiting case where is isolated from all other particles. In this case it is represented by a Fock state of the field and this state has the charge $-e$. However a bound electron is not a Fock state. In fact we don't have a simple description of this state but we can approximate it as a sum of Fock states and it is these extra states in the sum that represent the virtual particles.

The point of this is that in the atom there will be virtual electron positron pairs present, and if we are adding the modulus of the charges these will change the total. This is a very small effect in a hydrogen atom because the binding energy is tiny compared to the rest mass of the electron and positron, but it does mean the average number of electrons differs from one by a tiny amount. That means the total amount of negative charge present differs from $-e$ by a tiny amount (the net charge remains unchanged due to the positive charge of the virtual positrons).

But does this mean the charge of the electron changes as it is bound into a hydrogen atom? I think this is largely semantic, though my answer would be *no* since strictly speaking the object bound into the hydrogen atom is slightly different from a free electron.

Answer (score 1):

There are many experimental proofs since the Milican oil drop. Electron trajectories are measured with great accuracy in electron ( and positron) beams. The accuracy depends on the charge of the electron which does not change no matter how many kilometers the colliders are.

It would come out as an apparent nonconservation of energy in the results.

The LEP experiments which established the standard model would have completely different results, too.